# Cannot write to mySQL db or read from it in my buffalo application

Tags: mysql, go, buffalo

Currently i have the problem, that my buffalo application cannot write to my MySQL db or read from it. But in the logs no errors occurring.

**My database.yml file**

```
development:
  dialect: "mysql"
  database: "test_buff"
  host: "localhost"
  port: "3306"
  user: "root"
  password: "password"
```

**worker.go**

I created this model with POP.

```
type Worker struct {
ID        uuid.UUID `json:"id" db:"id"`
CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" db:"updated_at"`
Name      string    `json:"name" db:"name"`
Age       int   `json:"age" db:"age"`
Plz       string    `json:"plz" db:"plz"`
```

}

**models.go** (auto generated)

```
// DB is a connection to your database to be used
// throughout your application.
var DB *pop.Connection

func init() {
    var err error
    env := envy.Get("GO_ENV", "development")
    DB, err = pop.Connect(env)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pop.Debug = env == "development"
}
```

**home.go**

```
a := models.Worker{}
tx, ok := c.Value("tx").(*pop.Connection)
if !ok {
    //
}
tx.All(&a)
```

If i use another mySql driver(not the buffalo) than it works. So it might be a problem with the buffalo framework

**Code with the other driver**

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@/test_buff")
```

Comment: The by yourself indicated critical connection code is not in the question, making it extremely difficult to say anything useful

Comment: Do you know, in which part of the application could be the problem? I thought, that it is some configuration problem.

Comment: Please add more info about where the problem is: you said "buffalo application cannot write to my MySQL db or read from it", but what result do you see ? What did you try to do?